# Парсинг строки (Java)

Tags: java

Добры день! 
Нужно написать метод, который будет делить строку на массив строк по разделителю точка, а затем поместить разделенные строки в HashMap. Метод написан, но он только помещает одну строку из трех.

```
public static Map<String ,String> parse(String line) {
           Map<String, String> sentence =  new HashMap<>();
           String [] sentences = line.split("[.]");
           for (String s:sentences) {
               sentence.put("Sentence", s);
           }
           return sentence;
    }
```

String l = "la. la. la.";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас добавляются одинаковые ключи и предыдущие значения затираются. Вот пример, как вы можете сделать.

```
package stringsToHashMap;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/830181/Парсинг-строки-java
 * 
 * @author vvm
 */
public class StringsToHash {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String l = "la.la.la.";
        Map<String, String> sent =  new HashMap<>();
        sent = parse(l);

       //вывод значений
        for (String value : sent.values()) {
        System.out.println("Value: " + value);
        }

    }
    public static Map<String ,String> parse(String line) {
           Map<String, String> sentence =  new HashMap<>();
          // String [] sentences = line.split("[.]");
           String [] sentences = line.split("[,;:.!?\\s]+");
           int i = 0;
          for (String s:sentences) {
               sentence.put("Sentence"+i++, s);
           }

           return sentence;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Из [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

> A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one
>   value.